# How to Mask a custom shape inside a Container (Flutter)?

Tags: flutter, mobile, shapes

I would like to code the red and green triangle but I really don't know how to handle those.

[Figma](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygDtq.png)

I already code the card widget:

```
        //Card form fulfiled by IMG from the profile
        Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.5533,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.075,
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.grey,
                spreadRadius: 1,
                blurRadius: 10,
                blurStyle: BlurStyle.outer,
              )
            ],
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage('assets/img1.JPG'),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        //The rectangle containing Nickname & Tags
        Positioned(
            top: 20,
            right: 20,
            child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                child: BackdropFilter(
                    filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 10, sigmaY: 10),
                    child: Opacity(
                        opacity: 0.3,
                        child: Container(
                          height:
                              MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 9.6082474,
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2.1182266,
                          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                            color: Color(0XFFD9D9D9),
                          ),
                        ))))),
        //The Nickname of the user
        Positioned(
            top: 15,
            right: 25,
            child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                child: userNickname("Paul", context))),
        // Tags
        Positioned(
            top: 90, right: 90, child: tags("#EFREI", context, Colors.purple)),

        //The code for the red and green triangle to insert
      ]);
```

**The idea is to create the custom shape (triangle) and then mask it in the card in order to have rounded borders in the triangle. Any idea how to do it ? Thanks a lot**

I already tried something using CustomPaint but as you can see, the result is not great:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFkHx.jpg)

```
    Positioned(
            top: 360,
            child: CustomPaint(
              painter: CustomShape(blurSigma: 30),
            ))
```

And my CustomShape class :

```
class CustomShape extends CustomPainter {
  double blurSigma;
  CustomShape({required this.blurSigma});
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    var paint = Paint();
    // TODO: Set properties to paint
    paint.color = const Color(0XFFFF0000).withOpacity(0.8);
    paint.maskFilter = MaskFilter.blur(BlurStyle.inner, blurSigma);
    var path = Path();
    // TODO: Draw your path
    path.lineTo(100, 240);
    path.lineTo(0, 240);

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: The attempt looks like it worked fine. The only issue is you blurred the crap out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Spacer();

use the container spacing including multiple two widget,
or use
SizeBox(Mediaquery.of(context).size.width * .03); we can use...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).